Where is the file downloaded by the `xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS`?
I executed xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS for download ios17.2 simulator.
The download is complete, but the installation process failed due to lack of space and nearly 7 gigs of hard drive space was lost. I wanted to know where the downloaded file was placed so that I don't download it again.
error message ::
mac@omids-iMac-Pro Downloads % xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS    
Downloading iOS 17.2 Simulator (21C62): Installing (registering download)...2024-05-16 20:53:04.667 xcodebuild[1207:114064]  DVTDownloadable: Registering simulator runtime disk image at file:///Users/mac/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/com.apple.dmg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK17_2-17.2.0.0.dmg failed: Cannot copy the image because the disk is almost full
Downloading iOS 17.2 Simulator (21C62): Error: Error Domain=DVTDownloadableErrorDomain Code=29 "Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000767b330 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.simdiskimaged.SimDiskImageError Code=14 "Cannot copy the image because the disk is almost full" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot copy the image because the disk is almost full}}}

nothing in /Users/mac/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/
macos ventura 13.6.7
xcode 15.2

Once downloaded the .dmg is moved to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Cryptex/Images/Inbox -> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/Inbox.
After installation, stored to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images
Xcode 15.2
macos ventura 13.6
